# placing a tooltip in the center of the visible part of a polygon?

Tags: leaflet

Say I have a polygon that goes off screen. A part of it is visible, on screen, but the bulk of it isn't. I'd like the [tooltip](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tooltip) to be shown in the center of the visible part of the polygon.

Any idea as to how I'd do that?